# Proving inequality: For $0<\varepsilon<1 \in \mathbb{R},$ and $0<x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $x^n-n\varepsilon x^{n-1}\leq (x-\varepsilon)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This inequality is in a proof to show that for any positive real number, y , there exists a positive real number, x, such that $y^n = x$.

So, he says that you can deduce $x^n-n\varepsilon x^{n-1}\leq (x-\varepsilon)^n$ from the following inequality: $1-n\varepsilon\leq (1-\varepsilon)^n$. Also note that the professor sets $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{nNx^{n-1}}$. Can someone list the steps for proving this inequality from the other? I already proved the one that we are using to deduce the new one.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $x^n$ and use $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon x$.

Comment: So after you multiple both sides by $x^n$, then do you just have to show that $x^n (1-\varepsilon)^n \leq (x-\varepsilon )^n$ by expanding out each one using the binomial theorem?

Comment: No, you'll need to change your $\varepsilon$, but that doesn't really matter since $\varepsilon$ is universally quantified.

Comment: Are the conditions in the theorem correct?  In particular, should $x$ be greater than $1$?  Otherwise $(x-\varepsilon)$ could be negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observation:

There may be an error with the conditions.  When $x=\frac{1}{4}$, $\varepsilon$ is close to $1$, and $n=3$, then the LHS is close to $-\frac{11}{64}$ while the RHS is close to $-\frac{27}{64}$.  This issue does not arise when $x>1$.

Sketch (when $x>1$):

Starting with
$$
1-n\varepsilon\leq(1-\varepsilon)^n,
$$
multiply both sides by $x^n$ to get
$$
x^n-n\varepsilon x^n\leq (x-\varepsilon x)^n.
$$
Now, replace $\varepsilon x$ by $\varepsilon'$ to get
$$
x^n-n\varepsilon'x^{n-1}\leq (x-\varepsilon')^n.
$$
Now you need to do is to check the conditions of the theorem, but you're helped by the fact that $\varepsilon$ in the original inequality can vary and $\varepsilon'>\varepsilon$ (by the condition on $x$).

Comment: Thank you so much for the sketch. I figured out my lapse in judgement now, and can finish the proof. :)

Comment: Clearly you're good at analysis. As a student, how should I approach learning this subject? For me, I struggle with the inequalities a lot! The theory almost always makes sense to me, but the technical inequalities really are hell for me. As I'm going through the text and I see steps in inequalities that I don't quite understand, how should I approach that? Should I just take the step in the proof for granted and continue on? I'm afraid this is a bad approach because it must be an important skill to proficiently handle inequalities.